# Docker logs from go container (log and fmt) stop after init

Tags: docker, go

I'm working on an application which consists of a number of go containers. I manage them with docker compose. Recently I've been having trouble getting logs out of them. When I run "docker logs [container-name]", I only see logs that were created during init for packages in my application, and during main before the service starts listening. Subsequent calls to log.Println or fmt.Println do not appear in the output of "docker logs".
Do you know what could be going on?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @Logan Shire, Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to write your logs into the /dev/stdout
or simply use

```
log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
```

From [log](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go) package